# How to add new crossSellings to Shopware 6 product in a Controller?

Tags: symfony, criteria, shopware

I have a dictionary of product id's linked to other product id's. For each product I want to create new cross-sellings (of lists of products) using the id's from the relationship mentioned above.
Is it possible to update the product cross-sellings in a controller?
Should it be done through update method or anything else?

```
$this->productRepository->update([$productData], Context::createDefaultContext());
```

Update or Upsert does not seem to do anything to the product either.

```
 $crossSellingData = [
    'id' => $crossSellingIds[0],
    'name' => 'First Cross Selling',
    'position' => 1,
    'type' => 'productList',
    'active' => true,
    'assignedProducts' => [
        [
            'productId' => "5f5365e2adb446f6958faa4257c0af6d",
            'position' => 1
        ]
    ],
];
$productRepository->upsert([['id' => $productId, 'crossSelling' => $crossSellingData]], Context::createDefaultContext());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so by using the `productCrossSellingRepository` (Table: `product_cross_selling`) instead.

```
$newCrossSelling = [
    'productId' => $mainProductId,
    'active' => true,
    'name' => 'First Cross Selling',
    'type' => 'productList',
    'position' => 1,
    'assignedProducts' => [
        [
            'productId' => $firstCrossSellingProductId,
            'position' => 1,
        ],
        [
            'productId' => $secondCrossSellingProductId,
            'position' => 2,
        ],
    ]
];

$this->productCrossSellingRepository->create([$newCrossSelling], Context::createDefaultContext());
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, what I was doing wrong was that I was trying to update the products instead of crossSellings. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

It should also be possible to add the cross-sellings over the product repository.
I see two problems in your original code:

1. The association is named `crossSellings`, you use `crossSelling`, because there is no field named `crossSelling`, the repository ignores that key, that's way your update has no effect
2. The association is a too many association, that means the repository expects a list of `crossSellings` instead of one crossSelling.

So these minor changes in your original upsert call should fix your problem:

```php
$productRepository->upsert([['id' => $productId, 'crossSellings' => [$crossSellingData]]], Context::createDefaultContext());
```

Note the trailing `s` in the name of the crossSelling-Association and the extra `[]` array around the crossSellingData